# How can I get string from Textbox in java

Tags: java, swt

I'm having a problem with the `textbox`. I'm trying to copy a file inside the arraylist and transfer it to another folder.

When I'm using this: `String strSource = "D:\\New folder\\";`
                   `String strDestination = "D:\\New folder\\Another Folder\\";`

It copies the file inside but when i change it to `String strSource = txtSource.getText();` and same with the destination there is no error but only `catch` but the destination folder is empty. If you guys confuse on my question i'll try to explain to you.

**Copy Method**

```
 public void copyFiles(String source, String destination){
        try {
            File fileFrom = new File(source);
            File fileTo = new File(destination);
            Files.copy( fileFrom.toPath(), fileTo.toPath());

        } catch (IOException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
            MessageBox msgBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.OK);
            msgBox.setText("Error");
            msgBox.setMessage("File is AlreadyExist."); //where this is the one catching..
            msgBox.open();
        }
    }
```

**Copy Button**

```
String strSource = new String(txtSource.getText());
String strDestination = new String (txtDestination.getText());
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> list = readConfigFileList(ConstantVariables.SPECIFIC_FILE_LIST);

                    for (String strList : list) {
                        copyFiles(strSource + strList, strDestination + strList);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete stacktrace (odds are good that it's already trying to tell you what the problem is).   Also, please provide a [mcve]...  Since you've stated that the file-copying code works, "minimal example" in this case probably means "prints the unexpected `String` returned by `getText`".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase My question is already answered by myself. Do i need to post my answer here?

Answer (score 0):

This one is the solution to me i just add `\\`.

`String strSource = txtSource.getText() + "\\;`